# How do I detect that SSL is broken on a page, using Selenium

Tags: ssl, selenium, https, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

We have pages where we occasionally see compromised SSL certificate because of third party scripts that load non HTTPS resources (Initially they're fine but they occasionally change). We would like to test those pages for broken SSL every day.

We have tried one approach, attempting to catch a pop-up message that would indicate that we have insecure content on the page. However, we have been unsuccessful in simulating the pop-up message through selenium. It appears that selenium has automatically disabled any popups. While we have identified a Selenium method to disable the suppression of the pop-ups(disable-popup-handler) but we have not been able to successfully see the popup even using this method.

Has anyone found a way to detect broken SSL pages using Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load a browser profile (with WebDriver) that doesn't have the setting for popup blocker enabled (using the Profile class and giving it the right properties).  Then, you will get the Windows popup message concerning the SSL cert.  If , for some reason, you cannot control the popup using WebDriver (because its limited to Action control only within the browser content window) then you can use Sikuli API to handle the dialog and export the cert to the "Downloads" dir and then copy the file to expected location for inspection.   Unfortunately, if you use Sikuli, that will make your automation script sequential and not work via a RemoteWebDriver grid server and so you wont be able to run parallel tests.   Hopfully, WebDriver gives  you access to the dialog and so you will be able to run with RemoteWebDriver because that is the best way to go when running scripts, even if you run a browser locally.